# How to get current domain in django views without `com` or `eu`?

Tags: django

```
http://www.website.com
http://www.website.eu
```

How to get current domain in django views without `com` or `eu`?

> http://www.website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do some manual labor to get just the domain name.

Using `request.META['HTTP_HOST']` will give you the domain, but it's generally a bad idea since it can be spoofed (ie. faked).

But let's play anyways! I will be using the Python slice syntax.

```
def domain(domain):
    return domain[:domain.rfind('.')]

>> domain(request.META['HTTP_HOST']) #http://www.website.whatever
>> "http://www.website"
```